# How to put my form on top of an image in css/html?

Tags: html, css

Good day developers! I would like to ask if how can I make my form appear on top of my image? The problem is that my form appear at the bottom. Here's the image of my screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of my Problem]

Here are my codes:

**HTML**

```
<body>

    <div class="container" align="center">
      <div id="image">
        <img src="assets/img/imac.png" style="width:640px; height:678">
      </div>

    <div id="loginForm">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Please sign in</h3>
       </div>
         <div class="panel-body">
           <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
            <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me"> Remember Me
              </label>
            </div>
          <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Login">
          </fieldset>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

   </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
background-color: #2ecc71;
}


.container {

width: 1000px;
height: 700px;
margin-top: 100px;
}

#loginForm{
width: 500px;
height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: set it as `background-image` for the form

Comment: But how? I tried setting it, but the image disappeared.

Comment: Use `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `#image` be `position:absolute` and fill the `.container` (*which is made `position:relative`*) with it.

```css
body {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 700px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position:relative;
}
#loginForm {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:10;
}

#image{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" align="center">
  <div id="image">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x678/cccccc/ffffff.jpg&text=monitor+image" style="width:640px; height:678">
  </div>

  <div id="loginForm">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Please sign in</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
              </label>
            </div>
            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Login">
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a div the size of the image, and make the image the background image for the div.

Then place a div container inside this div for the form itself. You can then use CSS to position the form div using margins.

```
<div id="image-container">
    <div id="form-container">
         // your form
    </div>
</div>

#image-container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: url(/* your image */);
}
#form-container {
    width:350px;
    margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
 }
```

Obviously, you need to replace the sizes with ones of your actual image, and the margin values to make your form content fit within the screen of the computer in your image.

That should work, I'm coding this on my phone so apologies if I miss something trivial!

Answer (score 1):

I used the last example and made it simpler. Just adjust for image size and use padding to position the form.

```
<div style="width:529px; height:220px; background-image:url('image.jpg')" align="center">
<div style="width:529px; padding: 165 0 0 0" align="center">
...form ...
<div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.form-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: url("https://parrot-tutorial.com/images/mask-smog.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 400px;
  padding: 24px;
}

.my-form {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 16px;
}

.form-header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: .25rem;
}

.form-text {
  color: #6c757d;
  display: block;
  margin-top: .25rem;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  user-select: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  background-color: #007bff;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
  <form action="/html/form-action.php" class="my-form" method="POST">
    <h2 class="form-header">Login</h2>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleEmail">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleEmail" placeholder="Enter email" name="uemail">
      <small class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="examplePassword">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="examplePassword" placeholder="Password" name="pwd">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" id="exampleCheck" name="saveinfo">
      <label for="exampleCheck">Remember me</label>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Reference:**[Add a Form on Image](http://parrot-tutorial.com/howto/howto_form_on_image.html)