# How to put Transparent HTML form on the top of sliding image in background using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have created HTML Page which I will be make dynamic using Spring MVC.
I am new to HTML, CSS,JS as well but I need to create banner images which will slide with certain internal.

**I need to do following things:**

1. Bannner Image  shoule slide with certain interval.
2. I need to put Fixed HTML Search form on the top of sliding images.
3. Currently banner  image is coming as center of the page I need to stretch to total with with of the page I have tried to change like `".imageslide{width:100%;.."` width 100% but it did not work.
   [image]

I Need to create exactly like bellow image:

[image]

Sliding banner Image I am able to make  with the  below HTML and JS code but Search Form on the top of sliding banner image I am not getting idea how can i make it: 
I have seeing this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580993/how-to-put-my-form-on-top-of-an-image-in-css-html) but I could not make solution out if it :(. 
**index.html**

```
<htm ng-app>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5" src="./angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Advent+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="withinheader">
            this is header
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="slideShowController" class="imageslide" ng-switch='slideshow' ng-animate="'animate'">
            <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="1">
            <img src="./S_43_HomeDestinationImages_FriMar0420161099.jpg" alt="">
            </div>  
            <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="2">
            <img src="./S_43_HomeDestinationImages_FriMar042016420.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="3">
            <img src="./S_43_HomeDestinationImages_FriMar042016575.jpg" alt="">
            </div>  
            <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="4">
            <img src="./S_43_HomeDestinationImages_FriMar0420161099.jpg" alt="">
            </div>  
        </div>  
        <div id="mainbody">
        this is body
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
function slideShowController($scope, $timeout) {
 var slidesInSlideshow = 4;
 var slidesTimeIntervalInMs = 3000; 

  $scope.slideshow = 1;
  var slideTimer =
    $timeout(function interval() {
      $scope.slideshow = ($scope.slideshow % slidesInSlideshow) + 1;
      slideTimer = $timeout(interval, slidesTimeIntervalInMs);
    }, slidesTimeIntervalInMs);
}
```

**style.css**

```
/* Styles go here */
#header {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #EE514B;
}

.slideshow {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  width:600px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  border-radius: .3em;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#withinheader {
    width:60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100px;
}

.imageslide{
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.imageslide .slider-content {
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:400px;

}

.animate-enter,.animate-leave {
    -webkit-transition:1000ms cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1) all;
    -moz-transition:1000ms cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1) all;
    -ms-transition:1000ms cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1) all;
    -o-transition:1000ms cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1) all;
    transition:1000ms cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1) all;
}

.animate-enter {
    left:100%;
}

.animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
    left:0;
}

.animate-leave {
    left:0;
}

.animate-leave.animate-leave-active {
    margin-left:-100%;
}



#mainbody {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width:50%;
    min-height:1024px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Please help  me on this
I need make this webpage using Angular JS, and MVC, how should I approach.

Thanks in advance for help and information to make it work.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle/plunker?

Comment: sorry i could not understand what you mean ?

Comment: This is a sample angularJS online demo, could you edit it and add your code to it for a working demo to your problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/Nk3zvUsiwLMac0sf4FET?p=preview

Comment: I make code running but i dont know how to upload image.Now it says i dont havve permission to change it. 
I never use that. I am sorry I took time for that.

Comment: I need to create similar like this "http://i.stack.imgur.com/HBXbU.jpg"  
@Dev can you help me, I am very new to Html and CSS. 
So i started with sliding of image example first.

Comment: You have to host images on a public url to use it as absolute path in html. Also, there is an option to fork the plunk up top so as to have your own plunker with all permissions.

Comment: Yes I have added some image now ..
but that is just demo i am trying I need create page like attache image link : http://i.stack.imgur.com/HBXbU.jpg

Comment: If you dont mind could you please chat with me for some time [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112578/discussion-between-karo-la-and-dev-one).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the complete HTML, I daresay this may just be a case of adding `position: relative` to the wrapper div css (.imageslide), and `position: absolute` (along with `left/right/top/bottom` css declarations as appropriate) to the search form container tag css.